# Can filters be used for pre and post processing?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

My understanding of filters is that they can be used only for preprocessing, and once their task is finished, they give control to the invoked resource, and then control never gets back to the filter. So they can never be used for post-processing?

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not right. A filter method that needs to pre-process and post-process typically looks like:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    preProcess(request, response);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    postProcess(request, response;
}
```